# machine learning problem:i made a new column in test data but instead of median value it is filled with NaN

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, regression

Here i am trying to predict the sales price by taking median of price with respect to area and mzzone
here are the values:

```
combo=pd.pivot_table(train,values=['SALES_PRICE'],index=['MZZONE','AREA'],aggfunc='median')
combo
```

output:

```
                        SALES_PRICE
 MZZONE  AREA   
    A   Adyar           7144042.5
        Karapakkam      5468500.0
        Velachery       8428745.0
    C   Adyar           7877645.0
        Karapakkam      6443000.0
        Velachery       9170660.0
    I   Adyar           8785350.0
```

but when i try to put it in test data by making a new column, it is filling NaN in full column
here is the code i used to put the median values in test data:

```
test['super_mean']=0
s2 = 'MZZONE'
s1 = 'AREA'
for i in test[s1].unique():
  for j in test[s2].unique():
    test['super_mean'][ (test[s1]==str(i)) & (test[s2]==str(j)) ] = train['SALES_PRICE'][ (train[s1]==str(i)) & (train[s2]==str(i)) ].median()
```

why this is happening so??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in the code within the 'j' for loop. You have an 'i' where should be a 'j'. This is the correct for loop:

```
test['super_mean']=0
s2 = 'MZZONE'
s1 = 'AREA'
for i in test[s1].unique():
  for j in test[s2].unique():
    test['super_mean'][ (test[s1]==str(i)) & (test[s2]==str(j)) ] = train['SALES_PRICE'][ (train[s1]==str(i)) & (train[s2]==str(j)) ].median()
```

Comment: Whole column of sales price is filled with values

Comment: Before predicting with respect to 'MZZONE' and 'AREA', i tried it only for 'MZZONE' and it is working fine i.e. filled the median value in column

Comment: the indexes 'i' and 'j' in the train part are wrong, there is a 'i' where should be 'j'

Comment: train[s2]==str(i) should be train[s2]==str(j) for more clarity

Comment: This foolish mistake made me suffer a lot